# Ionic 3 - Getting params to sigin a user with ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic3, login-page

I already researched and watched some videos, but it was still not very clear as to my doubt. It may be quite simple, but I have difficulty. If anyone can help me, I'm grateful.

I have this Login Page:

```
<form id="login-form1">
    <ion-list id="login-list2">
      <ion-item id="login-input1">
        <ion-label>
          Email
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input type="email" placeholder=""></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item id="login-input2">
        <ion-label>
          Password
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" placeholder=""></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <div class="spacer" style="height:40px;" id="login-spacer1"></div>
    <button id="login-button1" ion-button color="stable" block on-click="goToHome()">
      Log in
    </button>
    <button id="login-button2" ion-button clear color="positive" block href-inappbrowser="/signup">
      Or create an account
    </button>
  </form>
```

And this Ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
  goToHome(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  }
}
```

And I need log in a user, in my function goToHome, i need email and psw.
How i can get this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form and get the inputs like this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="goToHome()">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="loginInput.email" name="email" type="email" placeholder=""></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="loginInput.password" name="password" type="password" placeholder=""></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button type="submit" block>Add Todo</button>
</form>


export class LoginPage {
  loginInput = {};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  goToHome() {
    console.log(this.loginInput)
  }
}
```

The main idea is to use `ngModel` to get all your inputs. 
Note: If you use ngModel within a Form tag, you have to provide a name property.

Use the guide on how to create forms here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/forms/